# Error handling function not working within dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, rvest, mutate

Why is R complaining about an error when my function already handles errors?

I've created a function to grab the parent element of an href attribute which invariably is "<a>". The function has some error handling to return NA if it can't find the href attribute.

The function works just fine in isolation, but not in combination with dplyr::mutate. I can't figure out why that is.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
# Create html doc
html.test <- "<a href=\"hello\"</a><a id=\"ctl00_ctl00_btnSearch\" data-action=\"search\" class=\"go\" href=\"javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00%24ctl00%24btnSearch','')\"><span>GO</span><i class=\"fal fa-search\"></i></a>" %>%
  minimal_html()

# Create function
fun.get.node.name <- function(href.target){
  # treat warnings as errors
  options(warn=2)  
  
  xpath <- paste0("//a/@href[.= \'", href.target, "\']/..")
  
  res <- try({
    node_name <- html_nodes(x = html.test, xpath = xpath) %>% html_name()
  }, silent = TRUE)
  
  if (inherits(res, "try-error")) {
    # print warnings as they occur
    options(warn=1)  
    return(NA)
  } else {
  # print warnings as they occur
  options(warn=1)
  return(node_name)
  }
}
```

Now, if I apply the function to the attribute href = "hello", it works fine both in isolation and when applied within dplyr::mutate:

```
href.target <- "hello"
fun.get.node.name(href.target)
[1] "a"

data.frame(href = href.target) %>% mutate(node_name = fun.get.node.name(href.target = href))
   href node_name
1 hello         a
```

But, if I apply the same function to the attribute href = "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00%24ctl00%24btnSearch','')" (which for some reason can't be found) then the function works only in isolation and NOT when applied within dplyr::mutate:

```
href.target <- "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00%24ctl00%24btnSearch','')"
fun.get.node.name(href.target)
[1] NA

data.frame(href = href.target) %>% mutate(node_name = fun.get.node.name(href.target = href))
 Error: (converted from warning) Problem while computing `node_name = fun.get.node.name(href.target = href)`.
ℹ Invalid predicate [1206]
```

Why is R complaining about an error when the function already handles errors?

Comment: why are you calling: href.target = href in the pipe, its also the input df? did you try . (dot operator)?

Answer (score 0):

Your function handles errors correctly, but the error message that pops up says it has been converted from a warning. So your function should `suppressWarnings` as well and then it will work as expected.

Although this solves your problem, it is still not clear why the warning is thrown inside the `mutate()`, but not outside of it.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)


# Create html doc
html.test <- "<a href=\"hello\"</a><a id=\"ctl00_ctl00_btnSearch\" data-action=\"search\" class=\"go\" href=\"javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00%24ctl00%24btnSearch','')\"><span>GO</span><i class=\"fal fa-search\"></i></a>" %>%
  minimal_html()

# Create function
fun.get.node.name <- function(href.target){
  # treat warnings as errors
  options(warn=2)  
  
  xpath <- paste0("//a/@href[.= \'", href.target, "\']/..")
  
  res <- try({
    node_name <- suppressWarnings(
      html_nodes(x = html.test, xpath = xpath) %>% html_name()
    )
  }, silent = TRUE)
  
  if (inherits(res, "try-error")) {
    # print warnings as they occur
    options(warn=1)  
    return(NA)
  } else {
    # print warnings as they occur
    options(warn=1)
    return(node_name)
  }
}

href.target <- "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00%24ctl00%24btnSearch','')"
fun.get.node.name(href.target)
#> [1] NA

data.frame(href = href.target) %>%
  mutate(node_name = fun.get.node.name(href.target = href))
#>                                                      href node_name
#> 1 javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00%24ctl00%24btnSearch','')        NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this, but when I run your code (with an href that can't be found) `res` becomes an empty character vector and so `inherits(res, "try-error")` returns FALSE instead of TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Using the insight provided by @TimTeaFan I have a solution where I take advantage of the fact that `suppressWarnings()` will return an empty character vector when the code within cannot find the href. So I don't need to go down the error handling `try` path...

```
# Create function
fun.get.node.name <- function(href.target){

  xpath <- paste0("//a/@href[.= \'", href.target, "\']/..")
  
  node_name <- suppressWarnings(
    html_nodes(x = html.test, xpath = xpath) %>% html_name()
  )
  
  if (length(node_name) == 0){
    return(NA)
  } else {
    return(node_name)
  }
}

# Run
data.frame(href = href.target) %>% mutate(node_name = fun.get.node.name(href.target = href))

#> href                                                           node_name
#> javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00%24ctl00%24btnSearch','')        NA
```